# Do I need to write some guard for javascript file which require others?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say, I have main.js which contain a require

```
var BBB = new require('../bbb.js');
```

Later, I would like the same main.js to work in the browser, should I use the following to gaurd

```
if ( typeof require === 'object' ) {
   var BBB = new require('../bbb.js'); 
}
```

Comment: In the browser you can be confident that `require` is *not* defined unless you've included a library that implements it.

Comment: so I would like to know if adding if statement is good practice or not here

Comment: @AdamLee My personal opinion is not to use this as back-end and front-end are different apps by nature. combining them together would confuse things specially as the code grows.

Comment: There's no pointing testing for an object that is almost certainly not defined, because if you *need* to use it you will need to include a library that implements it and if you do that then you can be sure it will be available. So if anything, you'd have a test to decide whether to define it...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary to do that. If the user intends to use the code on the client side, they can use something like browserify.

You could use this if you intended to make different functionality on frontend than on backend (for example because some functions can be used only in a particular environment).